# Nuget custom server returns 404

Tags: nuget-server

I am trying to setup nuget custom server, and cannot get it list my packages.
Here is list which I verified:

- Server updated to .net 4.5
- OS is Windows Web Server 2008 R2
- Application pool is set to integrated, dotnet set to 4.0
- modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is present
- mime map is present in web.config, and visible by IIS
- I am able to download file with direct link
- i am able to push package to my server

So, when I go to http://servername.com i see nice:

You are running NuGet.Server v2.7.40911.225

Click here to view your packages.

but http://servername.com/nuget returns 404. Probably there is issue with original nuget routing.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the ODATA routes are just not being picked up. Did you check that nothing is overriding this at the machine.config level?  You may also want to check that your package path is configured, and the web app has permission to access it.

One thing that might be easier to do is to install a third-party NuGet server such as [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget); it's free and installs pretty easily, and also will be a bit more robust in terms of features.

(disclaimer: I work for [Inedo](http://inedo.com/))